# data not Showing when execute the stored procedure in Sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, inner-join

I write this code in my stored procedure:

```sql
ALTER PROC sp_ShowComplaintStatus (@pid bigint,
                                   @compid int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT PId,
           C.Compld,
           CC.ComplCategory,
           CSC.ComplSubCategName,
           S.Status
    FROM TN_Complaint C
         INNER JOIN TN_ComplStatus CS ON C.Compld = CS.CompId
         INNER JOIN Z_Status S ON CS.StatusId = S.StatusId
         INNER JOIN Z_ComplCategory CC ON C.CompCategId = CC.ComplCategoryId
         INNER JOIN Z_ComplSubCategory CSC ON C.ComplSubCategoryId = CSC.ComplSubCategoryId
    WHERE PId = @pid
      AND C.Compld = @compid;
END;


sp_ShowComplaintStatus 10001, 1000;
```

But when I execute my stored procedure, it doesn't show any records. It only show column name.

Comment: How do you know that you have records in database to satisfy your conditions? In any case you can always try to comment where PId=@pid and C.Compld=@compid and execute your SP to see if there are at least some records

Comment: probably there is lack of records in one from your tables that you are inner joining.
Remmeber inner join will show results only if there are associated rows in all tables.  Lack of row in just one table will affect the output by not showing this record. You could read about left/right/outer joins too, just for more clarity.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Please don't use HTML to format your code onto individual lines; [so] supports Code Blocks and Code Fences, which also syntax highlight. Also, an FYI: The prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: Please supply a [mcve] containing data that actually conforms to this query

Comment: I have checked that record in my database before executing this query.

Comment: I'm using sql Server.

Comment: *"I have checked that record in my database before executing this query. "* The fact remains, the reason you are getting no results is because there are no results that meet the criteria. Don't forget, you have `INNER JOIN`s above, so if your `JOIN` to `Z_ComplSubCategory` (for example) returns no related rows, the your entire query will return **no rows**.

Comment: You did a great job with writing consistently and with some best practices - EXCEPT for the reference to `PId`. Please fix it. I would argue that short and very similar aliases are not a good idea but in such a short query it does not matter too much. You SHOULD schema qualify your table names and include an ORDER BY clause (if order matters - usually it does).